# Tomcat is not working on Ubuntu Core

Tags: java, tomcat, ubuntu

I've installed tomcat7 on my linux ubuntu.
So , the port connector is 8080 as per default.

I tried to telnet the port , it showed refused to connect.
But the main page of the ip when typed in web browser

The results :

```
It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
```

Alright, so i telneting doesn't work but HTTP can connect.
So , i tried running the http://ip:8080//manager/html for tomcat also it showed 
me the below :

This webpage is not available

ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I don't have any firewall installed btw.

Is there anything i can do?

Answer (score 0):

I've realized there's some PID with unknown issue.
The issue was , I checked catalina log and found out java heap memory error.
Thus , I've killed some unwanted processes then walaa ! it worked !